# C# WiX installer Binary Element error

Tags: c#, .net, iis, wix

I'm trying to configure IIS Sites using a WiX Installer.
Somehow my installer keeps throwing me **the following error** (compile time error):

> The ComponentGroup element contains an unexpected child element 'Binary'.

Im trying to create a **Binary** element to add a certificate to the IIS Site.
**Code Sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">

  <Binary Id="myCert.Binary" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Certificates\myCert.pfx" />
  <Component Id="IISWebsiteFlex" Guid="{********-79BF-4317-****-317FE4C8DEAC}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDERFLEX" KeyPath="yes">
    <!--IIS Site aanmaken-->
    <iis:Certificate Id="ActaNet3Certificate"
                     StoreName="root"
                     Overwrite="yes"
                     Name="fabrikam.com"
                     StoreLocation="localMachine"
                     Request="no"
                     BinaryKey="myCert.Binary" 
                     PFXPassword="MyPFXPassword"                     
                     />
```

Usually the problem is in the XMLNS namespace but I did add:

> xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension"

Comment: The problem might be at the location where you include the file you posted. Is that inside a `ComponentGroup` element? Then you have to move the `<?include file.wxi>` instruction to the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wix reference states for [Binary](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/binary.html) tag

> Parents
>
> Control, Fragment, Module, Product, UI

Your code fragment seems to have the `<Binary>` and `<Component>` tags as children of `<Include>` (??). Are you missing a `<Fragment>` tag?

Also, should that be Include? Or should it be Wix

```
<Wix
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
  
  <Fragment> ... </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have included this in the **Fragment** element